# When did DIP packages get bigger?

Tags: history, dip

The dual in-line package was invented in 1964, and it appears that they existed in 14- and 16-pin variants by 1965 (as evidenced by an image in [this December '65 article](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electronics-mag/fairchild-semiconductor-electronics-mag-dec-13-1965.htm) in Electronics Magazine).

My 1976 copy of TI's TTL Data Book indicates that they were manufacturing TTL chips in 14-, 16-, 20-, 24- and 28-pin packages by that time. In later years, 8-bit CPUs were commonly available in 40-pin packages, and Wikipedia's article on the [DIP package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package) suggests they got as large as 64 leads.

Can anyone provide a list of dates showing when these various sized packages were first manufactured/sold, to give an illustration of how the technology changed over time?

---

My bookshelf only goes as far back as 1976. At locations such as archive.org, bitsaver, et.al, so far I have Fairchild's 36-pin 9035 64-bit memory cell from 1969, Intel's 8080 40-pin microprocessor from 1974, and Motorola's 64-pin 68000 from 1979 as earliest examples of each pin count.

As to why I "need" these dates, apart from historical curiosity, I have an old (1970s?) prototyping system that only supports DIP chips up to 36 pin. In the microprocessor boom, 40-pin chips were *everywhere*, so it intrigues me that this one only goes up to 36.

Comment: The MC68k was in a 64 pin DIP, introduced in 1979; I do not know if other devices preceded it. This was before SMT products got going and the number of pins rarely had anything to do with die size - it was based on the number of signals required.

Comment: And 18-pin, like the 8008 (~1971). It wasn't so much the technology keeping pin count down, rather any actual *needs*. Once the microprocessor revolution started pin counts (roughly) skyrocketed overnight.

Comment: The TI 9900 was out before the 68k by a few years IIRC.

Comment: The 36-pin Fairchild 9035 seems to be a bit of an oddball in 1969: it has sixteen address lines for a 16x4-bit memory array, no multiplexing of address lines at all. I don't know whether that's for speed / minimum gate delay, manufacturing limitations, or something else. Either way, Intel's 3101 did a 16x4-bit chip in a 16-pin chip in the very same year.

Comment: I've found an earlier example of a 64-pin chip, a TRW MPY-16AJ multiplier, that was developed from 1976, with a pictured example dated 1978: http://www.cpushack.com/2017/12/19/chip-of-the-day-trw-mpy-16aj-making-multiplication-manageable/